# How to handle run time errors of java in jenkins during gradle buiild or somewhere else?

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

Sometimes when I do Gradle build to generate JARs,

```
gradle clean build -x Test
```

It passes (compile time), but while running generate JAR, it fails (runtime error)

Is there any way that can be handled in Jenkins so that if it is going to throw errors while running we can fail the build.

One solution I am thinking of is running the test case, not to exclude it as it will load context. Not sure if it works.

Is there any optimal solution?